# Load CSV file + landscape

Tags: pgfplotstable, landscape, datatool, csv, csvsimple

I hope someone is able to help me. I'm trying to create landscape pages, that are holding my survey items. After several tries with CSV files, I wrote everything by hand, but it's just too inflexible, so I wanted to give it another try.

In my first tries the sample CSV had a first column with the category name, but as I didn't manage to load it, I decided to make an own file for each category. Just in case anybody has an idea how to do it with one file only.

I tried so many combinations already, one time there is a problem if the questionnaire is spanning multiple pages, the other time (datatool), I got an issue with the citation. I'm using biblatex with biber backend.

Is it not possible to import a CSV file with citations in it?

I tried it with this sources so far:
[CsvSimple + Datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82218/display-top-border-of-table-using-csvreader),
[Pgfplotstable + Citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309676/citations-in-pgfplotstable/309682),
[Datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210946/custom-table-from-csv-file-multiple-header-rows), and several more...

Best regards,

Lisa

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
category,original,source,modified,reason,translated,
PE1,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[1]{testcite},This is no test sample.,Not sure.,ABC,
PE2,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[1]{testcite},This is no test sample.,Not sure.,ABC,
PE3,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[3]{testcite},This is no test sample.,Other reason.,ABC,
PE4,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[2]{testciteother},This is no test sample.,Not sure.,ABC,
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%What to write so it's working?
\end{document}
```

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of doing this: an easy way with `\csvautotabular` and a more controlled way with `\csvreader`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
category,original,source,modified,reason,translated
PE1,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[1]{testcite},This is no test sample.,Not sure.,ABC
PE2,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[1]{testcite},This is no test sample.,Not sure.,ABC
PE3,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[3]{testcite},This is no test sample.,Other reason.,ABC
PE4,This is a Test sample.,\textcite[2]{testciteother},This is no test sample.,Not sure.,ABC
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csvsimple}% csv reader and formatter
\usepackage{biblatex}%  since csv file contains \textcite
\usepackage{booktabs}%  better formatting of tables   
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}% to put in landscape 

\begin{document}

  \csvautotabular{test.csv}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{*6l}\toprule
      Category& Original& Source& Modified& Reason& Translated\\\midrule
      \csvreader[head to column names, late after line=\\]{test.csv}{}%
         {\category& \original& \source& \modified& \reason& \translated}%
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]